# How to prevent changing pivot table primary id when syncing many to many relation in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I'm using the pivot table primary id so it shouldn't change by syncing.

The `sync` method in many to many table will delete all records in pivot table and reinsert it.

Here's my solution:

```
        $variationUnits = collect($variationUnits);

        foreach ($variationUnits as $variationUnit) {
            if ($variation->units->contains($variationUnit['unit_id'])) {
                $variation->units()->updateExistingPivot($variationUnit['unit_id'], $variationUnit);
            }
            else {
                $variation->units()->attach([$variationUnit]);
            }
        }

        foreach ($variation->units as $variationUnit) {
            if (! $variationUnits->pluck('unit_id')->contains($variationUnit->id)) {
                $variation->units()->detach($variationUnit->id);
            }
        }
```

Is there any built-in feature to do that? if not, how can I improve it?